# Is it possible to determine if a URL is masking mine server side?

Tags: c#, dns, masking

Is it possible to determine if the current request for a given site is actually from a domain setup to forward with masking?  I've tried the following but they all return information about the 'actual' URL:

- Request.Url.DnsSafeHost
- Request.Url.AbsolutePath
- Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
- Request.Url.Host
- Request.Url.OriginalString

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "masking"?

Comment: Are you talking about `http://mysite.com/` masking to `http://www.mysite.com` ?

Comment: no, more like http://mysite.com masking to http://someotherdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the UrlReferrer property  for a known domain that would be doing the masking:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```